# Invert table rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, jquery-selectors

I want to invert table **tbody rows** with jQuery.

**WHAT I HAVE:**

```
<table width="630" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<thead>
 <tr>
    <td>TITLE A</td>
    <td>TITLE B</td>
```

(...) continue in jsfiddle.

Here what I have and what I want: **http://jsfiddle.net/ZaUrP/1/**

Comment: Please post the code you've tried.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dfygrvty/BAdyF/1/)

pretty much the same as the other guy, only I use .detach() which is guarunteed to keep any crazy events that were attached to the `tr`s intact.  I also use $.makeArray to avoid reversing any of the `proto` stuff on the base jQuery object.

```
$(function(){
    $("tbody").each(function(elem,index){
      var arr = $.makeArray($("tr",this).detach());
      arr.reverse();
        $(this).append(arr);
    });
});
```

Comment: Perfectly valid!! Want to up vote this, but i ran out of votes... :(

Comment: This is an awesome answer. I modified your answer and created a jQuery plugin [below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29413393/1762224).

Comment: This does not work for me because I have some cells spanning multiple rows using 'rowspan'

Answer (score 12):

Try this:-

Get the array of `tr`s from `tbody` using `.get()` and use [Array.reverse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) to reverse the elements and assign it back.

```
var tbody = $('table tbody');
tbody.html($('tr',tbody).get().reverse());
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XD3tn/)

In case you have events to `tr` or any containing elements you could just attach it using delegation, so that the reversed elements also get them delegated.

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/N4FGV/)

Comment: If you have any events attached to the any of the elements inside the table better go with @DefyGravity answer.

Answer (score 4):

```
$('tbody').each(function(){
    var list = $(this).children('tr');
    $(this).html(list.get().reverse())
});
```

Demo `-->`  http://jsfiddle.net/ZaUrP/5/

Comment: .get().  awesome. +1 as well.

Comment: This works very well for sorting visible rows in place!

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a jQuery plugin called `$.reverseChildren` which will reverse all the specified children of a given element. Credit goes to [DefyGravity](https://stackoverflow.com/users/176818/defygravity) for his insightful and intriguing use of `$.makeArray`.

I have not only reversed the rows of a table, but also the columns.

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.reverseChildren = function(childSelector) {
    this.each(function(el, index) {
      var children = $.makeArray($(childSelector, this).detach());
      children.reverse();
      $(this).append(children);
    });
    return this;
  };
}(jQuery));

$(function() {
  var tableCopy = $('#myTable').clone(true).attr('id', 'myTableCopy').appendTo(
    $('body').append('<hr>').append($('<h1>').html('Reversed Table')));

  tableCopy.find('tr').reverseChildren('th, td'); // Reverse table columns
  tableCopy.find('tbody').reverseChildren('tr');  // Reverse table rows
});
```

```css
*     { font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial; }
h1    { font-size: 16px;         text-align: center;     }
table { margin: 0 auto;                                  }
th    { background: #CCC;        padding: 0.25em;        }
td    { border: 1px solid #CCC;  padding: 5px;           }
hr    { margin: 12px 0;                                  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Original Table</h1>

<table id="myTable" width="320" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <thead>
        <tr> <th>Header A</th> <th>Header B</th> <th>Header C</th> </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr> <td>Data 1A</td>  <td>Data 1B</td>  <td>Data 1C</td>  </tr>
        <tr> <td>Data 2A</td>  <td>Data 2B</td>  <td>Data 2C</td>  </tr>
        <tr> <td>Data 3A</td>  <td>Data 3B</td>  <td>Data 3C</td>  </tr>
        <tr> <td>Data 4A</td>  <td>Data 4B</td>  <td>Data 4C</td>  </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is late, but it can help some other users looking for an answer

```js
function reverseTable() {
  var table = document.getElementById("table")
  var trContent = []
  for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
    trContent.push(row.innerHTML)
  }
  trContent.reverse()
  for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
    row.innerHTML = trContent[i]
  }
}
```

```css
table {border-collapse: collapse}
table, td {border: 1px solid black}
```

```html
<html>
  <body onload="reverseTable()">

  Original Table
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1,1</td>
        <td>Cell 1,2</td>
        <td>Cell 1,3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 2,1</td>
        <td>Cell 2,2</td>
        <td>Cell 2,3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 3,1</td>
        <td>Cell 3,2</td>
        <td>Cell 3,3</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <br>

  Reversed Table
  <table id="table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 1,1</td>
        <td>Cell 1,2</td>
        <td>Cell 1,3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 2,1</td>
        <td>Cell 2,2</td>
        <td>Cell 2,3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cell 3,1</td>
        <td>Cell 3,2</td>
        <td>Cell 3,3</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</body>
</html>
```