# Can I exchange data between view and JsonResult method using ViewBag?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, jsonresult

I'm implementing sorting for a table in my view, where it gets populated through ajax calling `JsonResult` method
this is the header link I use for ordering:

```
<a style="cursor: pointer" onclick="getData('@Html.Raw(ViewBag.Sort == "asc" ? "desc" : "asc")')" id="sort">Title</a>
```

the `JsonResult` method:

```
public JsonResult BooksData(string sort)
{
    ViewBag.Sort = ViewBag.Sort == "desc" ? "asc" : "desc";
    var books = new List<Book>();
    if (sort == "asc")
    {
        books = db.Books.Include(b => b.Author).OrderBy(b => b.Title).ToList();
        ViewBag.Sort = "desc";

    }
    else
    {
        books = db.Books.Include(b => b.Author).OrderByDescending(b => b.Title).ToList();
        ViewBag.Sort = "asc";

    }
    return Json(books, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

the `getsData` function:

```
function getData(sort) {
            var srt = sort;
            $('#tbl>tbody').empty();

            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/Book/BooksData?sort=' + srt,
                dataTtype: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (index, val) {
                        $('#tbl>tbody').append('<tr><td>' + val.Title + '</td><td>' + val.Author.Name + '</td></tr>')
                    });
                }
            });
        }
```

but the value of `ViewBag.Sort` is always `asc`?

Comment: `ViewBag.Sort = sort == "desc" ? "asc" : "desc";`

Comment: The first line of code - the value of the RHS `ViewBag.Sort` is always `null` (you have not set it yet) so the value of the LHS `ViewBag.Sort` is always `desc` and then your `else` block sets it to `asc`

Comment: This sounds correct and logical, but it still always `asc`, doesn't change!

Comment: Why are you also reversing it again in the `onclick()` in your view. Bit hard to understand what your wanting to do here

Comment: I removed this part to be `getData('@ViewBag.Sort')` but when I click the link the `sort` value becomes empty `""`

Comment: Am I correct in assuming you want to click on a link and reverse the order of the rows in a table (i.e. sorted by `Title`) aach time you click the link? And why call a server to do this as opposed to just using client side code (all the data is already in the view)

Comment: I'm coding as much I know now, with little knowledge of JS so I used `ViewBag`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130743/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-mohamed-ahmed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are numerous issues with your code. First `@Html.Raw(ViewBag.Sort == ...)` is razor code and is evaluated on the server before the view is sent to the client so your generating

```
<a style="cursor: pointer" onclick="getData("asc")" id="sort">Title</a>
```

or `getData("desc")` depending on the value of `ViewBag.Sort` in the GET method that initially generated the view. No where do you ever change it so you ajax call always submits the same value for the parameter `sort`.

Then in the `BooksData()` method, you have logic errors (although they ultimately do not matter). Because you have not previous set a value for `ViewBag.Sort`, then

```
ViewBag.Sort = ViewBag.Sort == "desc" ? "asc" : "desc";
```

evaluates to

```
ViewBag.Sort = null == "desc" ? "asc" : "desc";
```

so the value of `ViewBag.Sort` is always `"desc"` which your `else` block then resets to `"asc"`.

But your method returns a `JsonResult`, not a view, so the `ViewBag` value is then lost and its value is never returned to the client.

Change your code in the view to

```
<a href="#" style="cursor: pointer" id="sort">Title</a>
```

and assign the initial value of `ViewBag.Sort` to a javascript variable so it can be toggled each time you click the link

```
var currentSort = '@Html.Raw(ViewBag.Sort)'
var url = '@Url.Action("BooksData", "Book")';
// handle the click event of the link
$('#sort').click(function() {
    // toggle the value
    currentSort  = currentSort == 'acs' ? 'desc' : 'asc';
    $('#tbl>tbody').empty();
    $.getJSON(url, { sort: currentSort }, function(data) {
        $.each(data, function (index, val) {
            .... // append table rows
        });
    });
});
```

and the controller method is then

```
public JsonResult BooksData(string sort)
{
    if (sort == "asc")
    {
        var books = db.Books.Include(b => b.Author).OrderBy(b => b.Title); // no need for .ToList()`
        return Json(books, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    else
    {
        var books = db.Books.Include(b => b.Author).OrderByDescending(b => b.Title);
        return Json(books, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Note that you can do the 'sorting' on the client without the extra overhead of making call to the server by simply re-ordering the rows in the table using javascript/jquery - refer [Invert table rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16701671/invert-table-rows) for an example, although that means that any new records added to the database by other users after the view is first generated would not be updated in the view.

Comment: But can multiple columns be ordered using jQuery too, as the answer you referred to just reverse the rows?

Comment: Yes, but its gets a bit more complex and you need to use the `.sort()` function. The answers to [How to sort an array of objects by multiple fields?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913512/how-to-sort-an-array-of-objects-by-multiple-fields) will give you a starting point.